Не получается вызывать функции с нужными аргументами через кнопки (tkinter), созданные в цикле
Имеется цикл, в котором создаются кнопки (CustomTkinter). При выводе интерфейса все кнопки выводятся правильно, но при попытке их использовать, при нажатии любой из кнопок, в функцию передаются аргументы из 3-й кнопки.
Есть ли возможность передачи аргументов именно той кнопки, которая была нажата?
def button_event(index):
    text = button_learn.cget('text')
    print(index, text)

indexes = [1, 2, 3]
num_row = 1
for index in indexes:
    num_row = num_row + 1
    func = lambda: button_event(index)
    button_learn = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=in_process, text=index, command=func)
    button_learn.grid(row=num_row, column=5, pady = 5)



command=lambda i=index: button_event(i)

Тут лябмда видит index как глобальную переменную (ее последнее значение), а не запоминает текущее значение на момент создания лямбды. Решается передачей значения через параметр лямбды, как выше написали
